# Compile and render with parent context in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm creating a component that needs to render out of a bunch of concated strings. Vue's `compile` and `h` functions accomplish this quite nicely while having access to the parent context (unlike the template option).

However, the compiled text itself has no access to the parent context. Here's my simplified code:

```html
<script setup>
    
    import {compile, h, computed } from 'vue'
        
    const props = defineProps(['commTemplate', 'content']);
        
    const textStyle = computed(() => ({
        fontSize: props.commTemplate.textSize + 'px',
    }));
        
    const titleTyle = computed(() => ({
        fontSize: props.commTemplate.titleSize + 'px',
    }));
        
    const structure = [];
    const parts = [];
    structure[0] = `
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td :style="textStyle"></td>
            <td>
                `; parts['thing'] = `
            </td>
            <td :style="titleStyle">Optional Part</td>
            <td>
                `; structure[1] = `
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    `;
                                                    
    const render = () => {
        
        return h(compile(structure[0] + parts['thing'] + structure[1]));
        
    };

</script>
<template>
    <render />
</template>
```

After running this, Vue complains about `textStyle` not being defined when it encounters `:style="textStyle"`.

Is there any way to render/compile this along with the parent context?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what's your goal here.

Why aren't you using the normal template syntax?

Comment: My goal was to figure out how to pass props to the render function, which I stated clearly.

I'm not using normal template syntax because Vue isn't capable of doing what I require. I'm writing an email builder that searches and replaces keywords in user content with blocks of HTML that are not valid. See parts['thing']? It starts with an end tag, and Vue will remove this along with other formatting. So tying strings together before Vue gets involved is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Any props can be passed on to the rendered component using something like this:

```js
return h(compile('template'), { prop1, prop2 });
```